# Find Dataframe value and return column number

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have multiple dataframes.

E.g

```
0   dd   aa
1   ff   qq
2   ff   gg
4   ff   df
```

Is it possible to find "gg" and then return the column number of where it was found. In the above example, it will return an integer of 1

Comment: gg is not on 1 only qq and ff there

Comment: What is `print (df.columns)` ?

Comment: @panda gg is in column 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compare values with [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html), select second tuple and if need first match select by indexing:

```
print (np.where(df == 'gg'))
(array([1], dtype=int64), array([1], dtype=int64))

print (np.where(df == 'gg')[1])
[1]

a = np.where(df == 'gg')[1][0]
print (a)
1
```

If possible some value not match is possible use `next` with `iter` for return first matched value or default value:

```
print (next(iter(np.where(df == 'gg')[1]), 'no match'))
1
print (next(iter(np.where(df == 'aaa')[1]), 'no match'))
no match
```

Comment: could you point to some resources for this type of filtering?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the columns can have names, you can find the (first) column containing 'gg' this way:

```
found = df.isin(['gg']).any()
column_name = found[found].index.values[0]
integer_index = df.columns.get_loc(column_name)
```

This finds `df.isin(['gg']).any()` finds 'gg' in the DataFrame and lists all columns containing.

Then the first column name is extracted using `found[found].index.values[0]`.

Finally the integer location of the column name is extracted by looking up the name in the column list.